# Why can't I use MySQLi in my connection file string?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am converting one of my applications to MySQLi from MYSQL but I have run into a problem I can't sort out.

I have used this code for years, and can't figure out how to convert this.
I keep getting error.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /home/cusrtg/public_html/newg/install.php on line 347

I'm trying to write this string to a file, but before it gets to file write function, it give me the error, but when I use MySQL instead it's fine.
why ?

here is the new string I'm trying to write to PHP file.

```
$connection_line = "<?php $con = mysqli_connect('$host', '$db_user', '$db_password', '$db_name') or die(mysqli_error()); ?>";
```

but when I used to do it with MySQL it works okay with no errors.

```
$connection_line = "<?php mysql_connect('$host', '$db_user', '$db_password') or die(mysqli_error()); ?>";
```

I have to add the `$con =`
to the new line to make MySQLi work....
but it won't let me do this. why ?

what am I missing here ?

thanks.

ok. so I have tried a new way that works.

new way to create connection line for file write

```
$connection_line = "<?php \$_host = '$host'; \$_db_user = '$db_user'; \$_db_password = '$db_password'; \$db_name = '$db_name'; ?>";
```

then in other files use

```
include "connect/connect.php";
$con = mysqli_connect($_host, $_db_user, $_db_password, $_db_name) or die(mysqli_error());
```

this works.
any reason this wouldn't be safe or ok to use ?

Comment: why you do this that awful way?

Comment: I'm just learning how to convert to mysqli and don't get all the differences yet. I understand you need to have connection in mysqli_query , so how else are you supposed to get the data from the configuration file into the query ?  you can't use  $con in the other files if it doesn't exist in the config file first. so.... how do I write it to the config file without this error ? and why is this way awful ? it's always been the way to do it with mysql. what's the difference doing it with msqli ? what is aweful about it ? and what way is better ?  how else can you write the config file ?

Comment: ummm,,,, that's what I'm doing ? asking a question to LEARN. why even post if you just want to be mean and not give the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with below code instead for mysqli.

**Code:**

```
$host = "localhost";
$hostname = "root";
$hostpassword = "";
$db_name = "DB";

$connect = new mysqli($host, $hostname, $hostpassword, $db_name);
if($connect->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL : ".$connect->error;
}
```

Comment: That won't work. You're using single-quoted strings.

Comment: nothing works to write the string to the config file with the $con =

Comment: but without it the string does not throw error and allows me to write it to the config file just fine. why can I not add the " $con = " part ??

Comment: does any one have a reasonable answer instead of just down voting my question and saying it's aweful ? there are no stupid questions. This is my first time using mysqli

Comment: Hi Charlie.Thanks so much for the answer. I will try that now, but I already came up with another way while I was messing around about 20 mintues ago. let me know what you think of this method. bad code or ok ?

Comment: new connection line for file write

Comment: @CodeSponge What Charlie HC has given you is the "standard", in your case, way of creating a connection. I am not sure why you are generating a file to include it when you can just write it like above and include that file? Are you generating this file from a Form like in an installer?

Comment: Hi Tim. yes, this is for the installer and it needs to write the connect.php file with the connection line in it, so that all scripts in the application can use one connection. but I don't want manual page editing required for the user, so the installer has to write the line to a connect.php file. the application is already written this way and I'm just converting my old mysql stuff to msqli becuase mysql won't work on many servers now. I've always been able to write the connect file no problem for mysql. but I'm new to mysqli. I can't just include the entire connection request in every script